# How to set url for particular controller action - Magento

Tags: magento

If I have module mymodule in which I have index Controller. In which I have subaction as 'subaction'

Normally I access page as

```
   http://www.mywebsite/index.php/mymodule/index/subaction
```

How can I set url from code such as

```
   http://www.mywebsite/index.php/subaction
   or
   http://www.mywebsite/index.php/mymodule/subaction
```

Note ::  I do not want to create new controller I want this in the same index controller.

Comment: Create another Acion function in that controller

Comment: @Daya  I don't want to create new controller or actiona its just that I want shorten url of controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Magento URL-to-controller matching works through the Standard router which expects URLs to have a specific form. If you want to change that you have a few options at your disposal:

1. Deprecated config-based URL rewrites
2. Create URL rewrite entries in core_url_rewrite table
3. Create a custom router class to match the URL patterns which you would like to use

When considering how URL matching should work, you need to consider how Magento will expect to build the URL using its native URL calculation tools as well as how to get requests to match.

Comment: can any way to use xml to such set route to this kind of action ?

Comment: See [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_rewrite()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L864)

Answer (score -3):

You can do this by using routes

in your bootstrap do the following

```php
protected function _initMyRoutes() {
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front  = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $router = $front->getRouter();

    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
    $router->addDefaultRoutes();
    $router->addConfig($config, 'routes');

    return $router;

}
```

and in the configs directory create a file called routes.ini and in it place the following

```ini
routes.myRoute.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.myRoute.route = "/subaction/" 
routes.myRoute.defaults.module = "mymodule"
routes.myRoute.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.myRoute.defaults.action = "subaction"
```

OR

you can add the route directly in your bootstrap with

```php
protected function _initMyRoutes() {
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front  = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $router->addDefaultRoutes();

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
        'subaction',
        array('module' => 'mymodule', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'subaction')
    );
    $router->addRoute('subaction', $route);

    return $router;

}
```

That should do the trick but be adviced using routes can really be a pain.

[More about routes in the ZF manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am new in magento, can you give me further details how can i modify bootstrap ?

Comment: Open it :) it's should be in the application folder (it's called Bootstrap.php)

Comment: This answer is not correct, as Magento is not a Zend Framework MVC app - I edited the tags to reflect this - it should be noted that Ponsjuh was answering the question based on the improper tags